# Outer product of a vector with itself: $\sum_{i,j} (v v^T)_{ij} \geq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given some vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a product $v v^T$, is the sum of the elements always equal or greater than zero?

- Is this some known property?
- How can we prove it?

Comment: Direct computation of $\sum vv^T$ shows it to be equal to $(\sum v_i)^2$.

Comment: You should specify what do you mean by "vector", i.e. clear out the ground vector space.

Comment: @Cave now I see it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v = (v_1,\ldots,v_n)^T$ and let $l: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function that maps $v$ to the sum of the elements of $A= v{v}^{T}$. We see that (comment: [Cave Johnson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/356819/cave-johnson)) $$f(v) = \sum_{i}\sum_j a_{ij} = \sum_i \sum_j v_iv_j = \sum_i v_i \sum_j v_j = \big( \sum_i v_i \big)^2,$$ hence larger or equal than zero for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.